# Local or development Google Cloud Firestore database with App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

In my previous App Engine projects I used the Cloud Datastore, and during development I could debug my app on the local server and it would use a local database, stored in a file I could wipe out if I wanted to start from scratch.

With Cloud Firestore, even when I'm running locally it's talking to my real cloud database. Is there still a local option? Note that I'm **not** talking about client-side persistence, I'm talking about a mock development DB.

Google [recommends](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/) setting up multiple projects if you want dev/staging/production, and I'm guessing that's the answer, but I'd like to know before adjusting my workflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a local emulator for Firestore when using the Firebase CLI:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup

Answer (score 0):

I think (now only a few months later) that this is supported.  When I run my app, using dev_appserver.py, I see a message

```
INFO     2019-02-14 00:08:56,030 admin_server.py:150] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
```

Going to that URL shows me all the instances I have been seeing.  These seem to persist even when the dev_appserver is restarted.  Reading this and other posts I was convinced that my development was using my actual cloud database, but going to https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myproject was showing completely different content.

Just to be sure (because google is google and everything is named the same) I'm using an appengine app and a gcloud project, storing things to Firestore using ndb.Models...

**Oh, but careful**. My app I was also using the cloudstorage (**blobstore?**) and even though the localhost:8000 showed these, **THESE WERE THE REMOTE INSTANCES**.

Comment: im also unable  to get app engine to talk to firestore emulator.